# Push array in object if some keys are same in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an code some like this ;

```
 var data = [
 {'times':'07:50','name':'bojes'},
 {'times':'07:50','name':'unknw1q2q'},
 {'times':'09:50','name':'rafik'},
 {'times':'11:50','name':'adit'},
 {'times':'15:50','name':'adit'},
 {'times':'15:50','name':'adrok'}
  ];
```

i will grouping the object *'name'* and push it into a new array if the *'times'* is same. I know its like playing array.reduce, findWhere in underscore js or something bad like that, but my logic is bad.

And i will happy if you  will  output my code like this ;

```
var newData = [
 {'times':'07:50','name': ['bojes','unknw1q2q'] },
 {'times':'09:50','name': ['rafik'] },
 {'times':'11:50','name': ['adit'] },
 {'times':'15:50','name': ['adit','adrok'] },
  ];
```

how can i did it ?
some people wanna help me ? thx before it

Comment: "but my logic is bad" - could you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: i can group the some object keys, 'times' exactly. But my object keys of 'name' looping so much, and not sorting by the 'times' , even it can list the data, but the data its not same with the keys 'time'

Comment: I meant edit your question with the code you're using to loop through the array. Creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question would help us understand your thought process (and spot obvious errors).

Comment: Ok, well, edit if you think its better then before

Comment: I can't edit your question and put your own code in - I don't know what you've already tried. Irregardless, you've already got some answers.

Comment: Ok, ok. Its my first question in stackoverflow and i dont know actually what can i do with the people answer in my question, so far if the answer is good, my respect too, then i've done with my problem now. Thx. Sorry my english is bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const data = [
  {'times':'07:50','name':'bojes'},
  {'times':'07:50','name':'unknw1q2q'},
  {'times':'09:50','name':'rafik'},
  {'times':'11:50','name':'adit'},
  {'times':'15:50','name':'adit'},
  {'times':'15:50','name':'adrok'}
];

const groupByTimes = data => Object.values(data.reduce((data, {times, name}) => {
  if (data[times]) data[times].name.push(name);
  else data[times] = {times, name: [name]};
  return data;
}, {}));

console.log(groupByTimes(data));
```

Alternatively, using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const data = [
  {'times':'07:50','name':'bojes'},
  {'times':'07:50','name':'unknw1q2q'},
  {'times':'09:50','name':'rafik'},
  {'times':'11:50','name':'adit'},
  {'times':'15:50','name':'adit'},
  {'times':'15:50','name':'adrok'}
];

const groupByTimes = data => Object.values(
  data.reduce((data, {times, name}) => Object.assign({}, data, {
    [times]: data[times]
      ? {times, name: [...data[times].name, name]}
      : {times, name: [name]}
  }), {})
);

console.log(groupByTimes(data));
```

Or, with [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const data = [
  {'times':'07:50','name':'bojes'},
  {'times':'07:50','name':'unknw1q2q'},
  {'times':'09:50','name':'rafik'},
  {'times':'11:50','name':'adit'},
  {'times':'15:50','name':'adit'},
  {'times':'15:50','name':'adrok'}
];

const groupByTimes = data => Object.values(
  data.reduce((data, {times, name}) => ({
    ...data,
    [times]: data[times]
      ? {times, name: [...data[times].name, name]}
      : {times, name: [name]}
  }), {})
);

console.log(groupByTimes(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` & `findIndex`.Use reduce to create a new array(map can also be used). Using `findIndex` get the index of the object from array where the `times` matches. If so then update the name array else create a new object and push in the accumulator array

```js
var data = [{
    'times': '07:50',
    'name': 'bojes'
  },
  {
    'times': '07:50',
    'name': 'unknw1q2q'
  },
  {
    'times': '09:50',
    'name': 'rafik'
  },
  {
    'times': '11:50',
    'name': 'adit'
  },
  {
    'times': '15:50',
    'name': 'adit'
  },
  {
    'times': '15:50',
    'name': 'adrok'
  }
];

let k = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  // check if the times is present

  let findIndex = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.times === curr.times
  })

  if (findIndex == -1) {
    let obj = Object.assign({}, {
      times: curr.times,
      name: [curr.name]
    })
    acc.push(obj)
  } else {
    acc[findIndex].name.push(curr.name)
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(k)
```

Comment: @Raffikbojjes please consider accepting this as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this efficiently by creating an object keyed to the thing you want to be unique —— `times` in this case. For each time create an object with an array to hold your values. At the end the `Object.values()` of the object will be what you want. This will be more efficient that searching the list each time for a duplicate:

```js
var data = [{'times':'07:50','name':'bojes'},{'times':'07:50','name':'unknw1q2q'},{'times':'09:50','name':'rafik'},{'times':'11:50','name':'adit'},{'times':'15:50','name':'adit'},{'times':'15:50','name':'adrok'}];

let res = Object.values(data.reduce((obj, curr) => {
    // if we haven't seen the time before make a new entry
    if(!obj[curr.times]) obj[curr.times] = {times: curr.times, name: []}
    // push the current name into the current time entry
    obj[curr.times]['name'].push(curr.name)
    return obj
}, {}))
console.log(res)
```